# Selector syntax

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to select the rows of a table that contain the word Contact.

```
<table>
<tr><td>bla bla</td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact: Mike.....</td></tr>
</table>
```

When I use `e.children().select(":contains(Contact:)").text()`  I get

`Contact: Mike.....  Contact: Mike.....  Contact: Mike....`   3  instances of what I want

If I try `e.children().select(":containsOwn(Contact:)").text()`  I get

```
Contact:
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = ...
Elements rows = doc.select("td:containsOwn(contact:)");

for( Element element : rows )
{
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Contact: Mike.....
```

If you want the `tr`-tag instead: `doc.select("tr:contains(contact:)");`